# Delete special character in from word in spark - scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I have a csv file on `French`, that contain a special character like `(é, à, è, ç)`. I put this csv file in hdfs via `spark 2 - scala 2.11`.
I did the transformation of data, then a transfert my dataframe to Elasticsearch 5.6.

These special character appears like a bizarre character in the Dashboard kibana.

I want replace these spacial character by there normal letter, like:

```
é = e
è = e
à = a
```

I did it, using two possible:

```
val urlCleaner = (joined_df2:String) => {
   if (s == null) null else s.replaceAll("é","e")
}
```

And

```
val newsjoined_df2=My_Dataframe.withColumn('nom_equipe', when(col('nom_equipe').equalTo('é'), 'e').otherwise(col('nom_equipe'))
```

But, it do not work.
Someone please can suggest me a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a an UDF

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions
import spark.implicits._

val removeChars = functions.udf((s:String) => {
         s.replaceAll("è","e")
          .replaceAll("é","e")
          .replaceAll("à","a")
          .replaceAll("ç","c")
})
```

And then call `withColumn` in your DF with that `UDF` sending it the column name:

```
df.withColumn("nom_equipe", removeChars($"nom_equipe"))
```

Here is a quick test:

Input:

```
+------------+
|  nom_equipe|
+------------+
|       héllo|
|     chénene|
+------------+
```

Output:

```
+------------+
|  nom_equipe|
+------------+
|       hello|
|     chenene|
+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I resolved it by adding : spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dfile.encoding=iso-8859-1
in the file config.proporties then I added also this command line in the command of loading the file csv from hdfs

Comment: Can you suggest me a solution for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274012/calculate-the-deviation-time-between-tow-dates?noredirect=1#comment85553831_49274012